# php pulling data from csv collcection

Tags: php, arrays, csv, object

I am taking data from a csv using this.

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

When I get a cell and var_dump it out I get this (an object).

```
CellCollection {#29068 ▼
                #title: null
                #items: array:1 [▼
                "total_likes" => 23030.0
```

However trying

```
 $results[1]['#total_likes'];
 $results[1]->'#total_likes';
 $results[1]->total_likes;
```

I cannot seem to extract the data from the object.

Comment: Do you mind providing which variable are you dumping, please?

Comment: `$results` is `CellCollection`? Then `$results->total_likes` should do it...!? Why the `[1]`?

Comment: My fault. 


It is a laravel collection, there are lots of nice methods to modify.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#available-methods